# $stateParams parameter undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routing:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('message', {
        parent: 'admin',
        url: '/message',
        templateUrl: './app/gol88/admin/messaging/page/list.page.html',
        controller: 'ListController as listCtrl'
    })
    .state('replyMessage', {
        parent: 'message',
        url: '/{ticketId:int}/reply', //this should have {id} as stateParams
        onEnter: ['$mdDialog', '$state', function($mdDialog, $state) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: ReplyController,
                controllerAs: 'replyCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/app/gol88/admin/messaging/page/dialog/reply.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:true
            }).then(function(response) {

            }, function() {
                $state.go('message');
            });
        }],
        onExit: ['$mdDialog', function($mdDialog) {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }]
    })
;
```

When I tried to navigate to replyMessage state for the first time and use the $stateParams.ticketId in my Controller I am getting the value. However, when I transitioned to message state , and try to transition to replyMessage state back again, the $stateParams.ticketId is now undefined. Why is that so?

This is my controller for replyMessage state:

```
    var ReplyForm = require('../model/reply_form.model');

ReplyController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'TicketApiService'];

function ReplyController($stateParams, TicketApiService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.ticket = null;
    vm.ReplyForm = ReplyForm;

    vm.addComment = addComment;

    init();

    function init() {
        console.log($stateParams.ticketId);
       /* TicketApiService.details($stateParams.ticketId)
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.ticket = response;
            })
        ;*/
    }

    function addComment() {
        TicketApiService.addComment($stateParams.ticketId, vm.ReplyForm.toPayload())
            .then(function(response) {s.
                vm.ticket.comments.unshift(response);
                vm.ReplyForm.reset();
            })
        ;
    }
}

module.exports = ReplyController;
```

Comment: Are you appending ticketId to the URL in ListController ?

Comment: yep, it appears in the URL correctly.

Comment: Maybe the promise is resolved only once? I don't know about the onEnter property in ui-router though but Im saying that because I know you can resolve promises within $stateProvider but these resolve only once...

Comment: @DevMoutarde does it have anything to do with promise being resolved? My $stateParams is the problem its not getting the URL parameters.

Comment: Yeah my bad I was misled @user7966651

Comment: Hi I was able to figured out what causes the problem. Apparently, the $mdDialog's controller ReplyController was unable to get the $stateParams. What i did was to resolve the $stateParams parameters and set it to local property of $mdDialog's show function.